# Deploying Prometheus to different kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-operator

We have a central monitoring cluster that monitors different k8s clusters (running various micro services)
Currently we’ve deployed prometheus using manifests but we plan to move to a prometheus operator.
My question is, is service discovery possible for prometheus in this kind of a set up? Will I be able to annotate my pods?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you'll be able to do service discovery with the Prometheus operator for Kubernetes.

However, it does not work as it does with a standalone Pormetheus server and the `kubernetes_sd_config` configuration.

With the operator, the service discovery works with a custom resource called `ServiceMonitor`. This resource works with label selector that target services with specific label. You can find an example [here, in the official github page](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md)